# Displaying and formatting nested SVGs

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, google-polyline

I'm trying to display a nested SVG (path) and I'd like to manipulate the "inner" SVG so that's it's centred and scaled based on an "inner bounding box" - let's say a square 500px^2.

Here's an example but I can't get my head around the viewport and scaling to do what I need it to do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #svg {
    background:silver;
}
path {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 0.0001;
    fill: none;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
<svg id="svg" height="800" width="624" viewport="0 0 800 624" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"></svg>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function latLng2point(latLng) {

    return {
        x: (latLng.lng + 180) * (256 / 360),
        y: (256 / 2) - (256 * Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI / 4) + ((latLng.lat * Math.PI / 180) / 2))) / (2 * Math.PI))
    };
}

function poly_gm2svg(gmPaths, fx) {

    var point,
    gmPath,
    svgPath,
    svgPaths = [],
        minX = 256,
        minY = 256,
        maxX = 0,
        maxY = 0;

    for (var pp = 0; pp < gmPaths.length; ++pp) {
        gmPath = gmPaths[pp], svgPath = [];
        for (var p = 0; p < gmPath.length; ++p) {
            point = latLng2point(fx(gmPath[p]));
            minX = Math.min(minX, point.x);
            minY = Math.min(minY, point.y);
            maxX = Math.max(maxX, point.x);
            maxY = Math.max(maxY, point.y);
            svgPath.push([point.x, point.y].join(','));
        }


        svgPaths.push(svgPath.join(' '))


    }
    return {
        path: 'M' + svgPaths.join(' M'),
        x: minX,
        y: minY,
        width: maxX - minX,
        height: maxY - minY
    };

}

function drawPoly(node, props) {

    var svg = node.cloneNode(false),
        g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'g'),
        path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'path');
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(svg, node);
    path.setAttribute('d', props.path);
    g.appendChild(path);
    svg.appendChild(g);
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', [props.x, props.y, props.width, props.height].join(' '));


}


function init() {

    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; ++i) {
        paths[i] = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(paths[i]);
    }

    svgProps = poly_gm2svg(paths, function (latLng) {
        return {
            lat: latLng.lat(),
            lng: latLng.lng()
        }
    });
    drawPoly(document.getElementById('svg'), svgProps)
}

//array with encoded paths, will be decoded later
var paths = ["ki{eFvqfiVqAWQIGEEKAYJgBVqDJ{BHa@jAkNJw@Pw@V{APs@^aABQAOEQGKoJ_FuJkFqAo@{A}@sH{DiAs@Q]?WVy@`@oBt@_CB]KYMMkB{AQEI@WT{BlE{@zAQPI@ICsCqA_BcAeCmAaFmCqIoEcLeG}KcG}A}@cDaBiDsByAkAuBqBi@y@_@o@o@kB}BgIoA_EUkAMcACa@BeBBq@LaAJe@b@uA`@_AdBcD`@iAPq@RgALqAB{@EqAyAoOCy@AmCBmANqBLqAZkB\\iCPiBJwCCsASiCq@iD]eA]y@[i@w@mAa@i@k@g@kAw@i@Ya@Q]EWFMLa@~BYpAFNpA`Aj@n@X`@V`AHh@JfB@xAMvAGZGHIDIAWOEQNcC@sACYK[MSOMe@QKKKYOs@UYQISCQ?Q@WNo@r@OHGAGCKOQ_BU}@MQGG]Io@@c@FYNg@d@s@d@ODQAMOMaASs@_@a@SESAQDqBn@a@RO?KK?UBU\\kA@Y?WMo@Iy@GWQ_@WSSGg@AkABQB_Ap@_A^o@b@Q@o@IS@OHi@n@OFS?OI}@iAQMQGQC}@DOIIUK{@IUOMyBo@kASOKIQCa@L[|AgATWN[He@?QKw@FOPCh@Fx@l@TDLELKl@aAHIJEX@r@ZTDV@LENQVg@RkA@c@MeA?WFOPMf@Ej@Fj@@LGHKDM?_@_@iC?a@HKRIl@NT?FCHMFW?YEYGWQa@GYBiAIq@Gq@L_BHSHK|@WJETSLQZs@z@_A~@uA^U`@G\\CRB\\Tl@p@Th@JZ^bB`@lAHLXVLDP?LGFSKiDBo@d@wBVi@R]VYVE\\@`@Lh@Fh@CzAk@RSDQA]GYe@eAGWSiBAWBWBIJORK`@KPOPSTg@h@}Ad@o@F[E_@EGMKUGmAEYGMIMYKs@?a@J}@@_BD_@HQJMx@e@LKHKHWAo@UoAAWFmAH}@?w@C[YwAAc@HSNM|Ao@rA}@zAq@`@a@j@eAxAuBXQj@MXSR[b@gAFg@?YISOGaAHi@Xw@v@_@d@WRSFqARUHQJc@d@m@`A[VSFUBcAEU@WFULUPa@v@Y~@UrBc@dBI~@?l@P~ABt@N`HEjA]zAEp@@p@TrBCl@CTQb@k@dAg@jAU^KJYLK@k@A[Js@d@a@b@]RgBl@[FMAw@[]G]?m@D_@F]P[Vu@t@[TMF_@Do@E_@@q@P]PWZUZw@vAkAlAGJOj@IlAMd@OR{@p@a@d@sBpD]v@a@`Aa@n@]TODgBVk@Pe@^cBfBc@Rs@La@RSPm@|@wCpDS^Wp@QZML{@l@qBbCYd@k@lAIVCZBZNTr@`@RRHZANIZQPKDW@e@CaASU?I@YTKRQx@@\\VmALYRQLCL?v@P|@D\\GJEFKDM@OCa@COOYIGm@YMUCM@]JYr@uAx@kAt@}@jAeAPWbAkBj@s@bAiAz@oAj@m@VQlAc@VQ~@aA`Au@p@Q`AIv@MZORUV_@p@iB|AoCh@q@dAaANUNWH[N{AJ[^m@t@_Av@wA\\a@`@W`@In@Al@B^E`@Wl@u@\\[VQ\\K`@Eb@?R@dAZP@d@CRExAs@\\Yt@{@LG\\MjAATINOXo@d@kAl@_AHYBOCe@QiBCm@Fq@\\wADo@AyGEeBWuB@YHu@Tu@Lk@VcCTo@d@aA\\WJE`@G~@FP?VI\\U~@sANO`@SfAMj@U\\WjAsAXS`@UNENALBHFFL?^Ml@Uj@]b@q@RUJSPkChEc@XcAb@sA|@]PaA\\OJKNER?TDTNj@Jn@?p@OfC@ZR`B@VCV_@n@{@l@WbACv@OlABnAPl@LNNHbBBNBLFFJ@^GLg@x@i@|AMP[X}@XOJKPET?l@LhAFXp@fBDRCd@S\\_@Ps@PQ@}A]S?QDe@V]b@MR[fAKt@ErAF~CANILYDKGIKe@{@Yy@e@sB[gA[c@e@YUCU?WBUHUNQPq@`AiArAMV[^e@Zc@JQJKNMz@?r@Bb@PfAAfA@VVbADn@E`@KHSEe@SMAKDKFM\\^dDCh@m@LoAQ_@@MFOZLfBEl@QbASd@KLQBOAaAc@QAQ@QHc@v@ONMJOBOCg@c@]O[EMBKFGL?RHv@ARERGNe@h@{@h@WVGNDt@JLNFPFz@LdBf@f@PJNHPF`ADPJJJDl@I`@B^Tp@bALJNDNALIf@i@PGPCt@DNE`@Uv@[dAw@RITGRCtAARBPJLPJRZxB?VEX_@vAAR?RDNHJJBh@UnBm@h@IRDRJNNJPNbBFRJLLBLCzAmAd@Uf@Gf@?P@PFJNHPFTH`BDTHNJJJ@LG`@m@^YPER@RDPHNNJRLn@HRLN^VNPHTFX@\\UlDFb@FHh@NP@HKPsB?}ASkCQ{@[y@q@}@cA{@KOCQDa@t@{CFGJCf@Nl@ZtA~@r@p@`@h@rAxBd@rA\\fARdAPjANrB?f@AtBCd@QfBkAjJOlBChA?rBFrBNlBdAfKFzAC~@Iz@Mz@Sv@s@jBmAxBi@hAWt@Sv@Qx@O`BA`@?dAPfBVpAd@`BfBlFf@fBdA~Cr@pAz@fApBhBjAt@H?IL?FBFJLx@^lHvDvh@~XnElCbAd@pGhDbAb@nAr@`Ad@`GhDnBbAxCbBrWhNJJDPARGP_@t@Qh@]pAUtAoA`Ny@jJApBBNFLJFJBv@Hb@HBF?\\"];

init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The example is using an encoded google polyline and this path is likely to change - I'd like to force any path to fit within the confines of a 500px square - centred.

Any pointers on how I can do this?  I know SVG is a bit tricky with absolute positioning.

This is vanilla SVG but I would consider using some js libraries if they can handle positioning better (any suggestions?)

EDIT:  Adding a mockup of what I'm trying to do
[image: Example]

Comment: Your example is not generating nested svg's... Regardless, to constrain the svg you are generating, set the `width` and `height` attributes to `500px`. Also, you have a `viewport` attribute on your `<svg/>` tag. Do you mean `viewBox`? or does that do something somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to have a 624*800px SVG, and in its middle an area of 500*500px in which to draw your path. To do that you can place a nested SVG of that size right where you want it. As you know the size of the outer SVG, you can easily compute the position by hand. In the markup, leave off the viewBox.

For the outer SVG you has some errors in xour code: the attribute name is `viewBox`, and for the values, width coems before height:

```
viewBox="0 0 624 800"
```

Later, when adding the path to that inner `<svg>` element (no `<g>` required), set its `viewBox` using the values from the path properties. That's all.

```js
function latLng2point(latLng) {

    return {
        x: (latLng.lng + 180) * (256 / 360),
        y: (256 / 2) - (256 * Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI / 4) + ((latLng.lat * Math.PI / 180) / 2))) / (2 * Math.PI))
    };
}

function poly_gm2svg(gmPaths, fx) {

    var point,
    gmPath,
    svgPath,
    svgPaths = [],
        minX = 256,
        minY = 256,
        maxX = 0,
        maxY = 0;

    for (var pp = 0; pp < gmPaths.length; ++pp) {
        gmPath = gmPaths[pp], svgPath = [];
        for (var p = 0; p < gmPath.length; ++p) {
            point = latLng2point(fx(gmPath[p]));
            minX = Math.min(minX, point.x);
            minY = Math.min(minY, point.y);
            maxX = Math.max(maxX, point.x);
            maxY = Math.max(maxY, point.y);
            svgPath.push([point.x, point.y].join(','));
        }

        svgPaths.push(svgPath.join(' '))

    }
    return {
        path: 'M' + svgPaths.join(' M'),
        x: minX,
        y: minY,
        width: maxX - minX,
        height: maxY - minY
    };
}

function drawPoly(svg, props) {

    path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'path');
    path.setAttribute('d', props.path);
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', [props.x, props.y, props.width, props.height].join(' '));
    svg.appendChild(path);
}

function init() {

    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; ++i) {
        paths[i] = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(paths[i]);
    }

    svgProps = poly_gm2svg(paths, function (latLng) {
        return {
            lat: latLng.lat(),
            lng: latLng.lng()
        }
    });
    drawPoly(document.querySelector('#svg svg'), svgProps)
}

//array with encoded paths, will be decoded later
var paths = ["ki{eFvqfiVqAWQIGEEKAYJgBVqDJ{BHa@jAkNJw@Pw@V{APs@^aABQAOEQGKoJ_FuJkFqAo@{A}@sH{DiAs@Q]?WVy@`@oBt@_CB]KYMMkB{AQEI@WT{BlE{@zAQPI@ICsCqA_BcAeCmAaFmCqIoEcLeG}KcG}A}@cDaBiDsByAkAuBqBi@y@_@o@o@kB}BgIoA_EUkAMcACa@BeBBq@LaAJe@b@uA`@_AdBcD`@iAPq@RgALqAB{@EqAyAoOCy@AmCBmANqBLqAZkB\\iCPiBJwCCsASiCq@iD]eA]y@[i@w@mAa@i@k@g@kAw@i@Ya@Q]EWFMLa@~BYpAFNpA`Aj@n@X`@V`AHh@JfB@xAMvAGZGHIDIAWOEQNcC@sACYK[MSOMe@QKKKYOs@UYQISCQ?Q@WNo@r@OHGAGCKOQ_BU}@MQGG]Io@@c@FYNg@d@s@d@ODQAMOMaASs@_@a@SESAQDqBn@a@RO?KK?UBU\\kA@Y?WMo@Iy@GWQ_@WSSGg@AkABQB_Ap@_A^o@b@Q@o@IS@OHi@n@OFS?OI}@iAQMQGQC}@DOIIUK{@IUOMyBo@kASOKIQCa@L[|AgATWN[He@?QKw@FOPCh@Fx@l@TDLELKl@aAHIJEX@r@ZTDV@LENQVg@RkA@c@MeA?WFOPMf@Ej@Fj@@LGHKDM?_@_@iC?a@HKRIl@NT?FCHMFW?YEYGWQa@GYBiAIq@Gq@L_BHSHK|@WJETSLQZs@z@_A~@uA^U`@G\\CRB\\Tl@p@Th@JZ^bB`@lAHLXVLDP?LGFSKiDBo@d@wBVi@R]VYVE\\@`@Lh@Fh@CzAk@RSDQA]GYe@eAGWSiBAWBWBIJORK`@KPOPSTg@h@}Ad@o@F[E_@EGMKUGmAEYGMIMYKs@?a@J}@@_BD_@HQJMx@e@LKHKHWAo@UoAAWFmAH}@?w@C[YwAAc@HSNM|Ao@rA}@zAq@`@a@j@eAxAuBXQj@MXSR[b@gAFg@?YISOGaAHi@Xw@v@_@d@WRSFqARUHQJc@d@m@`A[VSFUBcAEU@WFULUPa@v@Y~@UrBc@dBI~@?l@P~ABt@N`HEjA]zAEp@@p@TrBCl@CTQb@k@dAg@jAU^KJYLK@k@A[Js@d@a@b@]RgBl@[FMAw@[]G]?m@D_@F]P[Vu@t@[TMF_@Do@E_@@q@P]PWZUZw@vAkAlAGJOj@IlAMd@OR{@p@a@d@sBpD]v@a@`Aa@n@]TODgBVk@Pe@^cBfBc@Rs@La@RSPm@|@wCpDS^Wp@QZML{@l@qBbCYd@k@lAIVCZBZNTr@`@RRHZANIZQPKDW@e@CaASU?I@YTKRQx@@\\VmALYRQLCL?v@P|@D\\GJEFKDM@OCa@COOYIGm@YMUCM@]JYr@uAx@kAt@}@jAeAPWbAkBj@s@bAiAz@oAj@m@VQlAc@VQ~@aA`Au@p@Q`AIv@MZORUV_@p@iB|AoCh@q@dAaANUNWH[N{AJ[^m@t@_Av@wA\\a@`@W`@In@Al@B^E`@Wl@u@\\[VQ\\K`@Eb@?R@dAZP@d@CRExAs@\\Yt@{@LG\\MjAATINOXo@d@kAl@_AHYBOCe@QiBCm@Fq@\\wADo@AyGEeBWuB@YHu@Tu@Lk@VcCTo@d@aA\\WJE`@G~@FP?VI\\U~@sANO`@SfAMj@U\\WjAsAXS`@UNENALBHFFL?^Ml@Uj@]b@q@RUJSPkChEc@XcAb@sA|@]PaA\\OJKNER?TDTNj@Jn@?p@OfC@ZR`B@VCV_@n@{@l@WbACv@OlABnAPl@LNNHbBBNBLFFJ@^GLg@x@i@|AMP[X}@XOJKPET?l@LhAFXp@fBDRCd@S\\_@Ps@PQ@}A]S?QDe@V]b@MR[fAKt@ErAF~CANILYDKGIKe@{@Yy@e@sB[gA[c@e@YUCU?WBUHUNQPq@`AiArAMV[^e@Zc@JQJKNMz@?r@Bb@PfAAfA@VVbADn@E`@KHSEe@SMAKDKFM\\^dDCh@m@LoAQ_@@MFOZLfBEl@QbASd@KLQBOAaAc@QAQ@QHc@v@ONMJOBOCg@c@]O[EMBKFGL?RHv@ARERGNe@h@{@h@WVGNDt@JLNFPFz@LdBf@f@PJNHPF`ADPJJJDl@I`@B^Tp@bALJNDNALIf@i@PGPCt@DNE`@Uv@[dAw@RITGRCtAARBPJLPJRZxB?VEX_@vAAR?RDNHJJBh@UnBm@h@IRDRJNNJPNbBFRJLLBLCzAmAd@Uf@Gf@?P@PFJNHPFTH`BDTHNJJJ@LG`@m@^YPER@RDPHNNJRLn@HRLN^VNPHTFX@\\UlDFb@FHh@NP@HKPsB?}ASkCQ{@[y@q@}@cA{@KOCQDa@t@{CFGJCf@Nl@ZtA~@r@p@`@h@rAxBd@rA\\fARdAPjANrB?f@AtBCd@QfBkAjJOlBChA?rBFrBNlBdAfKFzAC~@Iz@Mz@Sv@s@jBmAxBi@hAWt@Sv@Qx@O`BA`@?dAPfBVpAd@`BfBlFf@fBdA~Cr@pAz@fApBhBjAt@H?IL?FBFJLx@^lHvDvh@~XnElCbAd@pGhDbAb@nAr@`Ad@`GhDnBbAxCbBrWhNJJDPARGP_@t@Qh@]pAUtAoA`Ny@jJApBBNFLJFJBv@Hb@HBF?\\"];

init();
```

```css
        #svg {
    background:silver;
}
path {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 0.0001;
    fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>

<svg id="svg" height="800" width="624" viewBox="0 0 624 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <svg x="62" y="150" width="500" height="500"></svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I envisaged but couldn't articulate! Thank you :)